# Joda-Time: Get first/second/last sunday of month

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime

In plain Java, I have this code to get the last Sunday of the month.

```
Calendar getNthOfMonth(int n, int day_of_week, int month, int year) {
    Calendar compareDate = Date(1, month, year);
    compareDate.set(DAY_OF_WEEK, day_of_week);
    compareDate.set(DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, n);
    return compareDate;
}
// Usage
Calendar lastSundayOfNovember = getNthOfMonth(-1, SUNDAY, NOVEMBER, 2012)
```

What is a **clean and elegant** way to achieve the same result using [`Joda-Time`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class Time {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getNthOfMonth(DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY, DateTimeConstants.SEP, 2012));
}


public static LocalDate getNthOfMonth(int day_of_week, int month, int year) {
    LocalDate date = new LocalDate(year, month, 1).dayOfMonth()  
             .withMaximumValue()
             .dayOfWeek()
             .setCopy(day_of_week);
    if(date.getMonthOfYear() != month) {
        return date.dayOfWeek().addToCopy(-7);
    }
    return date;
}
}
```

Comment: No, that code will give the Sunday in the last week of the month. E.g. for October 2012, it will return November 4th.

Comment: Right. I've added if statement. Now should be fine.

Answer (score 6):

This is quite an old post but possibly this answer will help someone. Use the java.time classes that replace Joda-Time.

```
private static LocalDate getNthOfMonth(int type, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, int month, int year){
    return LocalDate.now().withMonth(month).withYear(year).with(TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth(type, dayOfWeek));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try something like that:

```
public class Foo {

  public static LocalDate getNthSundayOfMonth(final int n, final int month, final int year) {
    final LocalDate firstSunday = new LocalDate(year, month, 1).withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY);
    if (n > 1) {
      final LocalDate nThSunday = firstSunday.plusWeeks(n - 1);
      final LocalDate lastDayInMonth = firstSunday.dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue();
      if (nThSunday.isAfter(lastDayInMonth)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("There is no " + n + "th Sunday in this month!");
      }
      return nThSunday;
    }
    return firstSunday;
  }


  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getNthSundayOfMonth(1, DateTimeConstants.SEPTEMBER, 2012));
    System.out.println(getNthSundayOfMonth(2, DateTimeConstants.SEPTEMBER, 2012));
    System.out.println(getNthSundayOfMonth(3, DateTimeConstants.SEPTEMBER, 2012));
    System.out.println(getNthSundayOfMonth(4, DateTimeConstants.SEPTEMBER, 2012));
    System.out.println(getNthSundayOfMonth(5, DateTimeConstants.SEPTEMBER, 2012));
  }
}
```

Output:

```
2012-09-02
2012-09-09
2012-09-16
2012-09-23
2012-09-30
```

Comment: Use java.time classes and `TemporalAdjuster` instead, to shorten this code. See [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45792784/642706).

Answer (score 3):

With Joda

Let's say we have a date:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2017, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0);
```

`First we need to know if the month has 31, 30, 28 or 29 days :

```
int lastofMonth = date.dayOfMonth().getMaximumValue();
```

From this we create a new date:

```
DateTime endOfMonth = new DateTime(2017, 6, lastOfMonth, 0, 0, 0);
```

The we find out what day of week the last day is:

```
int whatDayIsLast = endOfMonth.getDayOfWeek();
```

Now we can create a date, which will be the date of the last Sunday of the month:

```
DateTime lastSunday = new DateTime(2017, 6, lastOfMonth - whatDayIsLast, 0, 0, 0);
```

For my example (June 2017), the result will be:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(dtf.print(lastSunday);
```

2017-06-25

Comment: nice explanation

Answer (score 2):

```
   static LocalDate getNthOfMonth(int n, int day_of_week, int month, int year)
   {
      if (n == -1)
      {
         return getNthOfMonth(0, day_of_week, month + 1, year);
      }
      final LocalDate compareDate = new LocalDate(year, month, 1);
      if (compareDate.getDayOfWeek() > day_of_week)
      {
         return compareDate.withDayOfWeek(day_of_week).plusDays(7 * n);   
      }
      else
      {
         return compareDate.withDayOfWeek(day_of_week).plusDays(7 * (n - 1));    
      }
   }
```

Comment: Use java.time classes and `TemporalAdjuster` instead, to shorten this code. See [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45792784/642706).

Answer (score 2):

// Following method will give last Sunday of the given month and year

```
public Date getLastSunday(int month, int year) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(year, month + 1, 1);
    int dayOftheWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    int val = dayOftheWeek == Calendar.SUNDAY ? -7: -(dayOftheWeek-1);
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, val);
    return cal.getTime();
}
```

//  `obj.getLastSunday(Calendar.OCTOBER, 2014);`

Answer (score 2):

### Solution using Java-8 `java.time` API

***Get the local date on the last Sunday of the specified year and month:***

In order to achieve this with the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) of Java, you can pass [`TemporalAdjusters.lastInMonth(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#lastInMonth-java.time.DayOfWeek-) as an argument to any `LocalDate` of the specified year and month.

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.YearMonth;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(getLastSundayOfMonth(2020, 12));
    }

    public static LocalDate getLastSundayOfMonth(int year, int month) {
        return YearMonth.of(year, month)
                .atEndOfMonth() //Returns a LocalDate at the end of the month
                .with(TemporalAdjusters.lastInMonth(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-12-27
```

I've used [`YearMonth#atEndOfMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#atEndOfMonth--) to get the `LocalDate`. Instead of this, [`YearMonth#atDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#atDay-int-) can also be used.

***Get the local date on the nth day-of-week (e.g. 2nd Thu) of the specified year and month:***

you can pass [`TemporalAdjusters#dayOfWeekInMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#lastInMonth-java.time.DayOfWeek-) as an argument to any `LocalDate` of the specified year and month.

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.YearMonth;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(localDateOnNthDayOfWeekOfMonth(DayOfWeek.THURSDAY, 2, 2020, 12));
    }

    public static LocalDate localDateOnNthDayOfWeekOfMonth(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, int ordinal, int year, int month) {
        return YearMonth.of(year, month)
                .atEndOfMonth() // Returns a LocalDate at the end of the month
                .with(TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth(ordinal, dayOfWeek));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-12-10
```

Learn about Java-8 date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Note for Java 6 or 7 users:**

For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).